# Concourse CI/CD - passing concourse credentials as shell script parameters

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, pipeline, concourse

I am pretty much new and learning the ropes of setting up and running a concourse CI/CD pipeline.
One of my build tasks requires credentials stored in the concourse credential manager. They need to be passed as parameters to my shell script.
How do I pass them as arguments?

My shell script runs as : `ci/scripts/build.sh -u username -p password`

`username` and `password` are to be picked up from the credentials manager

my concourse pipeline task is set up as

```
    - task: build
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        source:
          repository: java
          tag: "8"
        type: docker-image
      inputs:
        - name: resource-repo
      outputs:
        - name: artifacts
      run:
        path: ci/scripts/build.sh            
      params:
        u: ((artifactory_user))
        p: ((artifactory_password))
```

This doesn't seem to work. I guess there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: Do you mean that they are stored in CredHub?

Comment: @TomFenech yes they are

Comment: I was also wondering if there is a way to set these params as environment variables before executing the task.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. From the task params [documentation](https://concourse-ci.org/tasks.html#task-params):

> `params: {string: string}` Optional. A key-value mapping of values
>   that are exposed to the task via environment variables.
>
> Use this to provide things like credentials to a task.

So your shell script becomes

```
ci/scripts/build.sh -u ${u} -p ${p}
```

Comment: The way to actually execute the shell script like that in the Concourse task is to include args so you have within your task: `run: {path: ci/scripts/build.sh, args: ["-u", "${u}", "-p", "${p}"]}`.